# Update SQL Table with INNER

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE SAP_FBL3N_MAIN
INNER JOIN SAP_FCHN_MAIN ON  (SAP_FBL3N_MAIN.[Check number] =  FCHN.[Check number from to] AND SAP_FBL3N_MAIN.[Type] = 'ZA'  AND SAP_FBL3N_MAIN.[Account]='105010' AND SAP_FCHN_MAIN.[Acct ID]='APIMM')

SET SAP_FBL3N_MAIN."MatchingStatus" = ('Cleared_SAP'+ CONVERT(varchar(256),SAP_FBL3N_MAIN.[ID]))
    ,SAP_FBL3N_MAIN."MatchingTimeStamp"= GETDATE()
    ,SAP_FCHN_MAIN."MatchingStatus" = ('Cleared_SAP' + CONVERT(varchar(256),SAP_FBL3N_MAIN.[ID]))
    ,SAP_FCHN_MAIN."MatchingTimeStamp" = GETDATE();
```

Throwing Error ,
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly state which table you are going to amend or update. Then update the new value in a specific column. And then, join another table with INNER. Finally, use WHERE cause to narrow the results

For example below

```
UPDATE 
    t1
SET 
    t1.c1 = t2.c2,
    t1.c2 = expression,
    ...   
FROM 
    t1
    [INNER | LEFT] JOIN t2 ON join_predicate
WHERE 
    where_predicate;
```